# How do you determine which portal a control field is created from?

Tags: ingress

I'm currently a L10 agent but until missions started I didn't really care where a Control Field was created from and this recently came up during a conversation. I'm trying to figure out which portal a control field is created from.

Given:

- We have portals A, B & C.
- We have already linked A to B
- While sitting at C we link C to A and we link C to B

My assumption would be that the Control Field would be created at portal C but I am not certain. This should be deterministic.

I am going to do some testing of theories related to this and I'll report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you carefully read the comm messages when creating fields you can see that the game prefers to acknowledge the originating portal of the last link as the field's name.

In your case, the last link which creates the field (It's either the link C to A or C to B, whichever closes the triangle between them and creates the field) would be originating from portal C and so the field would be announced as "martinatime created a Control Field @C".

Comment: In my personal testing that is what I found out too. Thanks for writing it up.